# Remove the strikethrough on deleted text in suggested edits

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review, suggested-edits, user-interface

I have also posted this feature request on [Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/371126/778756).

---

I recently reached 2k rep, so I've done my first few suggested edit reviews.

I reviewed [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1679634) edit, and I noticed something. The strikethrough through the removed text obstructed my view of the post before the edit, particularly the negative signs (-) (other things may be obstructed too, but in this case I noticed the negative signs).

The following screenshots are from Microsoft Edge at 100% (default) zoom:
[image]
Zooming in (to the screenshot, not on the webpage):
[image]
I've also tested on Firefox with similar results.

The text on top actually says "(-2a+4)", but the negative sign is literally indistinguishable from the skrikethrough. Given the already improper formatting in the post, it wouldn't surprise me if the original text actually just had a space (which are very common), i.e. "( 2a+4)", and this would look identical to "(-2a+4)" with the strikethrough.

All the other negative signs disappear too, and I also wouldn't be able to see if there actually were negative signs in the initial post where there are spaces.

This means I have no way of telling if the negative signs were added by the editor or part of the initial post.

**My request:** Remove the strikethrough through the removed text in suggested edits. The red block on the original side and the green block on the edited side are sufficient for the reviewer to see what has changed in the edit. The strikethrough unnecessarily obstructs view of the post.

I'm not sure if this post would be more suitable for Meta since it would affect multiple sites (or perhaps sites with MathJax, depending on what gets "obstructed" by the strikethough, although dashes on all sites are the same as minus signs anyway).

Given that I am new to the suggested edits review queue, and I couldn't find this being requested before, I would like to hear (read) others' view(s) on this too.

Comment: While I don't have the required reputation to *review* suggested edits, I noticed this situation with the strikethrough when just browsing the revision histories of some posts. It would be nice if the diff between revisions can be displayed in a better manner, but I'm not sure what that could be... A strikethrough is simple and unambiguous on text (without minus signs or dashes). Only relying on red/green color coding wouldn't be good for accessibility reasons... Maybe the vertical position of the strikethrough can be adjusted, so that the minus sign is not obscured?

Comment: @TheAmplitwist Having an uncentred strikethrough would likely upset far more people, and it might just obstruct other things instead (signs in exponents for example). I'm not sure exactly what accessibility issues this would cause (not saying there aren't any, just that I can't think of any), since even if a person can't differentiate between red and green, the red is always on the left side and the green is always on the right side, so the colour itself isn't really important, it is only necessary to highlight which parts have changed.

Comment: Some may be color blind.

Comment: Double strikethrough may be able to dodge the centered signs. I am not sure about the superscripts and subscripts.

Comment: @Roddy I thought I adressed this in my previous comment; the colours themselves aren't really needed, just the highlighting.

Comment: For whatever it's worth: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_blindness: "Red-green color blindness affects up to 8% of males and 0.5% of females of Northern European descent." That may be a small percentage of all people, but might include a significant percentage of current math.SE users.  It's true that highlighting alone would work, but color cues may make recognition quicker.  Green vs. red has particular salience (go/stop), but there is no blue-red colorblindness afaik, so that's another option.  (Red vs. blue is my go-to two-color combination for conveying information with colors.)

Comment: Crossposted on MetaSE https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/371126/778756

Comment: On a completely side note, I think a space instead of a minus sign is unlikely, since LaTeX/MathJax omits spaces in such places.

Comment: @BrianTung As in the example I showed, usually posts with such formatting don't use MathJax. I was referring to people using spaces after brackets, or spaces between symbols in general.

Comment: @JamesA: Ahh, yes, I see.

Comment: My experience might not be representative of everybody's, but I'm red-green colourblind and can absolutely tell the difference between the shades of red and green used here (if nothing else, the relative brightness of the two shades is enough).